# Safari does not stream certain video

Tags: safari, streaming, sonoma

I cannot play certain video streaming in Safari, while there is no problem in FireFox and Chrome. The platform is iMac 2012 OSX 14.3 (OCLP). On iOS there is no problem.The error is 'playback video decoding error'. The problem could be that I use an unsupported mac without metal, but that raises the question why other browsers perform correctly. Is there a fix for Safari?

[image]

Comment: This is a DRM issue related to OpenCore. Not a macOS or Safari issue. You should dive into OpenCore to figure it out. Even though the references are old, I suggest you start at https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Post-Install/universal/drm.html

Comment: Many thanks! The only option is to use a different browser then.